# Enable or disable a HyperLink in the RowDataBound-event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my code. I need enable or disable a **HyperLink** in the `RowDataBound` event in an ASP.NET GridView based on a value extracted from the database.

If the value of field `File` of my database is not `null`, the **HyperLink** is visible otherwise not. In GridView, I don't have planned to show the value of field `File`.

I've tried using these solution without success, because I have this error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

Here is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink Srl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Srl");     

        foreach (string color in colorList)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "File")))
            {
                Srl.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataBinder.Eval` returns an object. You need to convert that to a `String`.

Try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "File"))))
{
    Srl.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSLNO_BARCODE" runat="server"
                                 Value='<%#Bind("SLNO_BARCODE") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Use `asp:HiddenField` for File value and use this in row data bound event.

Answer (score 0):

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink Srl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Srl");     

        foreach (string color in colorList)
        {
            string str = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "File");

            //then you can check
            if (!String.IsNullorEmpty(str ))
            {
                Srl.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```